# Internet Explorer white page of death (but all other browsers are fine)

Tags: php, html, header

So i have remodeled my login system as i thought it was that giving me the error however I have further learned that the problem (white page of death) is not on that page but the landing page (myaccount.php).

At the top i have (hack for IE):

```
header ( 'P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"' );
```

This has no effect.

Does anyone know things which cause IE to blank page?

Thanks.

Ps i have tried other "logged in" pages and they all work fine.  This code below is the code before the HTML output:

```
include '../includes/dataBase.class.php';
page_protect();

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
mysql_query("update users set `online`='1' where `id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

// last posts from the user
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, linklabel FROM userpages WHERE author='$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pid = $row["id"];
    $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];

    $lastpost .= '<a href="../userposts.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel . '</a><br />';
}

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: enable php error reporting, use firebug or other development tools to trace any errors...

Comment: Hey so i added error_reporting(-1); to the top of the page no change, and i cant use firebug in IE can I?

Comment: Ie8 has a equivalent. just hit f12.

Answer (score 1):

If this code is working fine in the other browsers but not IE, you may need to look at the HTML that is generated.  Also, you may need to enable the error messages to appear in IE:

http://www.herongyang.com/VBScript/Error-Handling-Enable-Scritp-Debugging-in-IE.html

Comment: Hey, I had some errors from it but none anymore and the problem is still there :/

Comment: Is the page pretty large?  If not can you post some of the generated html?  What does the line generating the html output look like?

Comment: The page isnt too large no. I think the problem may be with the HTML markup however im not too sure. i tried validating it with w3c, every other page works fine thats the thing :/ and im not too sure what you mean by 'what does the line generating the html output look like'